# Populating a DataGridViewComboBox column from an ENUM and setting it - System.FormatException thrown

Tags: datagridview, enums, combobox, set

I guess I'm the latest to encounter this issue. I have tried several different approaches (based on other posts in this forum to creating a Yes/No DataGridViewComboBox column and populating its data source using an ENUM, and populating/setting it accordingly. I have been able to get the combo box on each row of the DataGridView to set properly according to the corresponding data.

Here is the ENUM I am using:

[image]

Here is the code I am using to populate it:

[image]
[image]

```
                            //
                            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                            //DataGridViewTextBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

                            cmb.DataPropertyName = "approved";
                            cmb.HeaderText = Get_Header_Text_For(cmb.DataPropertyName);
                            cmb.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                            cmb.HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
                            cmb.DefaultCellStyle = CStyleCenter;
                            cmb.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                            cmb.Name = approvedCheckCol;
                            cmb.DataSource = new List<AccessNCPCBase.YesNo>((AccessNCPCBase.YesNo[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(AccessNCPCBase.YesNo)))
                                                  .Select(value => new { Display = value.ToString(), Value = (int)value })
                                                  .ToList();
                            cmb.ValueMember = "Value";
                            cmb.DisplayMember = "Display";
                            cmb.Visible = true;
                            cmb.ReadOnly = false;
                            //
                            dgvParm.Columns.Add(cmb);
                            dgvParm.Columns[approvedCheckCol].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

Here is a screenshot of the populated (from the ENUM) data source for the new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn:

[image]

When I test the code, the following exception is thrown in the DataGridView's DataError event:

[image]
[image]

And here is the result:

[image]

Again, I have tried several of the approaches suggested in this thread. I even changed the code to add the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn before populating the DataGridView; My code was originally adding the column after populating the DataGridView, but an earlier poster mentioned that fixed their problem so I tried it, but no success.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong or what I am missing? Any suggestions and/or insights would, of course, be greatly appreciated.

Chris Fleetwood blkwebman@mindspring.com

Comment: It is curious “why” you are wanting to use an `enum` for this when you “know” an `enum` can NOT be used as a `DataSource` to the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`? Because of this, you are “creating” extra work for yourself. Also, it is unknown “what type” the values are in the “approved” column in the original data… I assume the original data contains `int` values… “0” for “No” and “1” for “Yes”. If you want to mate the combo box column to the `approved` column in the original data… you should add the combo box column “first” before assigning the grid a data source.

Comment: Also, you post a picture of the data error and it is clearly telling you that one of the items in the data is NOT a valid value for the combo box column. Example, if any number other than 0 and 1 is in the data, then you will get this error. It is unknown “what” this invalid value is, however, the error is clear. Have you checked all the values in the data before assigning it to the grids data source, to make sure each item contains a “0” or “1” in the “approved” column? This check should be done anyway, simply to avoid the data error. Can you elaborate on any of this?

Comment: @johng  #1. I didn't "know" an enum can NOT be used as a datasource to the DataGridviewComboBoxColumn.  My approach was based on various posts in this forum, some of which (including the one I selected) were upvoted by other esteemed colleagues.  That is what is leading me to ask the question.  Moreover, I have used an enum successfully in a ComboBox many times, and had hoped to be able to do the same for the column version.

Comment: @johng  Incidentally, as I mentioned in the original post, I have already tried adding the column before assigning the datasource.   Also, the DataGridView column on which the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn is based (specified by the DataPropertyName in the screenshot) is an integer column which contains the value 0 or 1.   The screenshot of the resulting ComboBox shows that the underlying data was an integer (1).  BTW, I DO understand the error in the screenshot.  Please don't make the assumption that I don't.  I am simply asking a question, With all due respect, I don't need the editorializing.

Comment: I was under the impression that you knew an `enum` would not work given the line of code…`cmb.DataSource = new List<AccessNCPCBase.YesNo>((AccessNCPCBase.YesNo[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(AccessNCPCBase.YesNo))).Select(value => new { Display = value.ToString(), Value = (int)value }).ToList();` … Also, a `ComboBox` and a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` are two (2) different things.

Comment: I am not trying to “criticize/editorialize” you in any way. I am sorry if you feel that way… it was not my intention. I was simply trying to understand how the data was structured. It is clear from the pictures that something is wrong if you want to display “Yes/No” instead of “0/1.” Understanding the underlying data is what I was specifically asking.

Comment: I will try another approach… Is it required that you use an `enum` for this? In addition, if you know what the error is, can you elaborate on “why” the error appears and what plans you have to fix/address this when it does appear. As I stated previously, you should check this anyway to prevent the error in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the combo box column works best with classes as opposed to `enums` or primitive types, I suggest you create a class specifically to use as an “Answer” for each item in the combo box column. Then you can use a list of this “Answer” class to bind to the combo box column. Below is a simple example.

```
public class Answer {
  public int AnswerValue { get; set; }
  public string AnswerDisplay { get; set; }

  public static List<Answer> GetYesNoList() {
    List<Answer> answers = new List<Answer>();
    answers.Add(new Answer { AnswerValue = 0, AnswerDisplay = "No" });
    answers.Add(new Answer { AnswerValue = 1, AnswerDisplay = "Yes" });
    answers.Add(new Answer { AnswerValue = 2, AnswerDisplay = "NA" });
    return answers;
  }
}
```

The `Answer` class has two (2) properties… `AnswerValue` is an `int` value “0/1” and an accompanying `AnswerDisplay` which is a `string` “No/Yes.” These properties will be used for the combo boxes `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`.

Next, we create a `static` method that returns the values we want in the list to “match” the values in the data. We will use this as a `DataSource` to the combo box column. Note the added “NA” entry… this is simply a suggestion as to what to do when you come across a value in the data that is NOT a 0 or 1. You will not be able to “ignore” these invalid values in the data, in this case if the value is invalid, you could set the value to 2 to indicate an invalid value.

Next to use this in the grid, you can use the code below to add the column before the data source is set in the grid.

```
private void SetComboCol() {
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
  cmb.DataPropertyName = "Approved";
  cmb.HeaderText = "Approved";
  cmb.Name = "approvedCheckCol";
  cmb.DataSource = Answer.GetYesNoList();
  cmb.ValueMember = "AnswerValue";
  cmb.DisplayMember = "AnswerDisplay";
  dgvParm.Columns.Add(cmb);
}
```

Agreed this is only one approach and I am confident there are other ways to achieve this.

As previously stated, even with this “approved” column set up properly in the grid. It is wise to check all the “Approved” values in the data. If you find a value in the “Approved” column that is not a 0 or 1, then set it to 2. This will at least minimize getting the grids `DataError` thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  For my part, I extend an apology to you.  I've been wrestling with this issue for a while and I have to admit my response was triggered by a kneejerk reaction to your original post.  However, one can always learn something new from someone else.  I'll try your suggestion and update the post status.

Comment: Incidentally - My original intent for the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` was to translate the `0 / 1` integer value to `Yes / No` in the combo box (and vice versa).

Comment: Using the approach in my answer, this “translation” is done automatically by the combo box cell when it is set up correctly. In other words, if the user changes a “No” to a “Yes” in the grid UI, then the underlying data source will change from “0” to “1.” However, as I stated previously, an often-overlooked important aspect is making sure the underlying data in the grid conforms to what items are in the combo box.

Comment: Unlike a regular `ComboBox`, the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` will throw the `DataError` if you try to put an item/text into one of the combo boxes cells that is NOT in its data sources list. The regular `ComboBox` will not throw an error and will simply ignore this. If you don’t check for these invalid values “before” you set grids data source, then, a `DataError` has a good chance of getting thrown. Checking for these invalid values is a definite CYA situation.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue using the `Answer` class.  As it turns out, the source field in the database (referenced as `DataPropertyName` in the code) was actually of (SQL Server) type `tinyint` (byte) instead of `int` (I changed that type reference in the `Answer` class).  That was the reason for the `DataError`.  I also addressed the CYA situation.  Thanks for your input.  Like I said, one can always learn from someone else.  Answer upvoted.